# Setup Ambari with HDP, and HDP-UTILS rpm for making a local repository

Tags: hadoop, ambari, hdp

I'm trying to install Ambari Server 1.7 on Oracle Linux 6 machine, but it turned out that it's not open source anymore. The public repository can't be accessed.

I've got an older version of Ambari's tar.gz file, after I successfully installed the Ambari server, when I build the Hadoop cluster, it was directed to the public repository that is no longer accessible for the HDP and HDP-UTILS repository. 
(*http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDP/centos6/2.x/GA/2.2.0.0*) 
(*http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.20/repos/centos6*)

So, I need those rpm files for making a local repository to build the cluster. I'm looking for the file through the internet but I can't find it anywhere, is there anyone who still has the file? 
(*HDP-2.2.4.2-centos6-rpm.tar.gz*) 
(*HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.20-centos6.tar.gz*)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ambari itself is still open source. HDP has been moved behind Cloudera's pay wall for a while.

You can use Apache Bigtop to deploy Hadoop clusters and get a public/free distribution of Ambari, but Ambari itself is no longer supported or developed, so I would not suggest using it to deploy Hadoop clusters (not even sure Bigtop supports Oracle Linux 6).

You can use any Ambari stack you want, too; you don't need those specific HDP / HDP-UTILS yum repositories, but there aren't any that are as publicly documented, from what I've found